# Content Approval Publish: Problem with any user except Site Collection Admin

Tags: workflow, publishing

When pressing the "Publish" button with any user that is not the site collection admin, I get an empty screen with "Start workflow" and no options. This happens even to a user with full control on the site. I have tried creating a new site collection and enabling publishing again to the same effect. Has anyone seen this before or can give any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The InfoPath form used as the workflow initiation form does NOT load if the site is not added to the trusted sites.